# Is there an effective attack as white after Nf3 with e5 response in Atomic chess?

Tags: opening, atomic-chess

I'm a typical player who enjoys the `1. Nf3` opening as white in Atomic chess games. Today in an online Atomic chess tournament, I come across a player who played the `1... e5` response. As `1... f6` is the typical response here, and `1... e5` doesn't protect the `G5` square, `2. Ng5` could be played. But since `3. Ng7` allows the black queen to escape to `E7`, or even worse to `H4` and threaten an explosion at `F2` on `2... f5` `2. Ng5` doesn't seem to lead to anything effective. What should be played next?

```
[FEN ""]
[White "Attacker"]
[Black "Defender"]
[Variant "Atomic"]

1. Nf3 e5?!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very interesting website with opening theory from the very first moves of atomic chess :
https://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~chess/atomic/

To answer your question, after :
1.Nf3 e5 ? 2.Cg5 f5 ! ( Qxg5 lose the queen and ...f6 3.Nf7 Qe7 4.Nd6+) 3.h4! (cover h4 square from the black queen) and then 3...c6 4.Nxh7! or 3....Bc5 4.d4 Bb6 5.Nf7 Qe7 6.Nd6 Kf8 7.Nxb7 both leads to massive destruction of Black camp.